# Razor View displayed incorrectly, un-readable content in VS2010 Sp1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

This has happened since yesterday, some razor views display like this in visual studio:

[image: Razor View Display Bug in VS2010 sp1]

I've repaired my VS2010 and the sp1 this morning, and still getting this.

If I minimize VS, the view display correctly, when going back to maximized mode it re-draw like that.

What can I do with that? Is there someone who got that situation, I cannot work like that.

Any idea? Do I have options?

**Edit**

As suggested, I updated the video card driver, and it seems to have fix the thing. Still 
very scary though.

**Edit 2**

Yes, after at least 1 reboot and 1 shut down, everything is back to normal. I would not have expected to update a video driver for a **"text editor"** ;).

In case it help someone else, I have an AMD Radeon HD 6800 series.

Comment: Something similar happened to me last April, though it wasn't just with the Razor views, it was all of VS (toolstrips, etc). I ended up having to reinstall Windows7. Hopefully that isn't the case for you. Could it be your video card or driver? Have you tried on a second monitor / video card? Have you tried rewinding to a restore point before yesterday?

Comment: That looks like a video card/driver problem to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text Editor in Visual Studio 2010+ uses WPF (which uses hardware-accelerated graphics rendering).  That might explain why you are seeing this problem in Visual Studio, but your problem definitely seems video card related.

Comment: I know but still, that mean I should make sure my customers required an up to date video driver for my WPF business app, it's a bit rough... Anyway, updating the driver also fixes ultra slow performance I had from a long time with Silverlight/WPF editor (not the designer) but the XAML code editing. That was really painful.